# Markov inequality for random variables with negative values.

Tags: random-variables

I'm given the maximum value of a random variable $X$ (for example $50$) and its mean, $\mathbb E(X)=20$. How do I find the upper bound to $P(X\le -10)$?

Comment: I think that you need to make the transformation $Y = X + 11$ and work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define new RV: S = 50 - R

E(S) = 30

P(R<=-10) = P(S>=60)

P(S>=60) = 30/60
                 = 1/2

You commented: I needed to clarify one last thing. P(50-X >= 60) <= 1/3

It should be 1/2 not 1/3.

Comment: How is the expectation 30. Can you please explain?

Comment: S = 50 -R so E(S) = 50 -E(R) .  Since E(R) = 20. We get E(S) = 30

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- $50-X$ is a nonnegative random variable since $50$ is an upperbound.
- Express your inequality in the form of $Pr(50-X \ge c)$.

Comment: So it should be like this : P(50-X >= -10) ?

Comment: $P(X \le -10) = P(-X \ge 10) = P(50-X \ge 60)$, now apply Markov on $50-X$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I needed to clarify one last thing. P(50-X >= 60) <= 1/3. Is this correct considering the typical formula of Markov inequality P(X >= a)? What I am trying to ask is that if a constant is added or subtracted in an interval such as in the above case, would it affect the final probability.

Comment: yes, it is correct. if it makes you more comfortable, let $Y=50-X$ and check that $Y$ is nonnegative. If you perform some operations and prove that the two conditions are equivalent, then the probability stays the same.

Comment: helloworld's answer is correct, the mean of the new variable is indeed $30$.